# Negative \vspace* too small

Tags: vspace

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe, nohead]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \vspace*{-3em}
    \rule{3em}{3em}
\end{document}
```

Why does the rule protrude into the text area?

[image: output]

As a comparison, this is how it looks without the `\vspace`:

[image: without vspace]

And this is what I would have expected:

[image: expected]

Comment: `\vspace*{-4em}`

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda no:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to consider both `\topskip` and `\lineskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe, nohead]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{\dimexpr-3em-\topskip-\lineskip}
\rule{3em}{3em}

\end{document}
```

[image]